# SQLite UPDATE syntax with field list

Tags: sqlite

I would like to update an existing row in SQLite using the following syntax:

```
UPDATE "table_name" SET ("field_1", "field_2") = ('value_1', 'value_2') WHERE "field_3"='value_3';
```

The [official documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html) suggests this should be possible, where the UPDATE statement must conform to this:

[image: SQLite UPDATE syntax diagram]

Which gives me this:

```
UPDATE qualified_table_name SET column_name_list = expr WHERE expr;
```

Where `column_name_list` must be:

[image: SQLite UPDATE column_name_list]

```
(column_name, column_name)
```

And where first `expr` can be:

```
(expr, expr)
```

But when I plug them all together (as in my first code snippet) SQLite gives me a syntax error:

```
near "(": syntax error:
```

Is this format possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: string literals require single quotes, you've used double quotes. (I'm not sureif the "relaxed parsing" rules apply here. details: https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

Comment: @peterchen Thanks for explaining correct quotes usage, I understand better now. Unfortunately I still get the same error (by luck my quotes were not a problem, I think). I have updated the question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `sqlite_version();` returns v3.9.2, please post as an answer and I will accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for [row values](https://sqlite.org/rowvalue.html) was added [version 3.15](https://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_15_0.html)

You need to upgrade to a recent version if you want to use that feature.